# Get all strings surrounded by specific text

Tags: vb.net, string, text

I have a filled textbox that contains image links multiple time, and I want to download them all.

Is there a way to get all the occurrences of links that starts with `https` and ends with `.png`, then get the ability to download the images ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    Dim testInput As String = TextBox1.Text
    Const pattern As String = "http(s)?://.*?\.png"
    Dim results As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(testInput, pattern, RegexOptions.Singleline)
```

**results** contains the image links.